# Indefinite Integral and the function

Tags: continuity, indefinite-integrals, riemann-integration

Let $f$ be a continuous function on $[a, b]$. Suppose that there exists a positive constant $K$ such that
$$
|f(x)| \leq K \int_{a}^{x}|f(t)| d t
$$
all $x$ in $[a, b]$. Prove that $f(x)=0$ for all $x$ in $[a, b]$.

It would be convenient if we replace the function $f$ with $g(x) = |f(x)|$, where $g$ is continuous and Riemann integrable on given domain.  $$ g(x) \leq K \int_{a}^{x}g(t) dt$$ is satisfied, and we assume there exists a point $x_{0}$ such that $g(x_0) > 0$. What could be the major strategies and original intuition behind finding a contradiction from here if one has only the continuity of $g$ and indefinite integral of $g$.

Comment: Does anyone has any further ideas or suggestions for how to proceed the problem?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By continuity of $f$, it is clear that the problem arises for $x$ close to $a$. First of all, we have

$$|f(a)|=\lim_{x\to a} |f(x)| \le \limsup_{x\to a} K \int_a^x |f(t)| dt = 0$$

by continuity of $f$, thus $f(a)=0$. Then define $x_\varepsilon:=\inf\{x>a:|f(x)|\ge \varepsilon\}$. We assume $f\neq 0$, thus for $\varepsilon$ small enough $x_\varepsilon$ is well-defined. There holds

$$\varepsilon \le |f(x_\varepsilon)| \le K\int_{a}^{x_\varepsilon}|f(t)|dt \le K(x_\varepsilon-a)\varepsilon\Rightarrow x_\varepsilon \ge \frac{1}{K}+a,$$

Clearly, $(x_\varepsilon)_{\varepsilon>0}$ is monotone decreasing for $\varepsilon>0$ and thus convergent, we denote the limit by $a_0$. Morever, $f(t)=0$ for all $a\le t\le a_0$ and moreover there is a sequence $t_n\to a_0$, $t_n>a$ with $|f(t_n)|>0$. By the above, $a_0>a$. Now, for all $x>a_0$ there holds

$$|f(x)|\le K\int_a^x |f(t)| dt = K\int_{a_0}^x |f(t)| dt.$$

We define $x_\varepsilon^0:=\inf \{x>a_0:|f(x)|\ge \varepsilon\}$. Since $f(t)=0$ for all $t\le a_0$ we have that

$$\varepsilon \le f(x^0_\varepsilon) \le K\int_a^{x^0_\varepsilon}|f(t)|dt=K\int_{a_0}^{x^0_\varepsilon}|f(t)|dt \le K(x_\varepsilon^0-a_0)\varepsilon$$
thus we deduce that $x_\varepsilon^0\ge \frac{1}{K}+a_0$. $x_\varepsilon^0$ again converges for $\varepsilon\to0$, and this time we can guarantee, that the limit is $a_0$ (because $|f(t_n)|>0$), a contradiction to the above lower bound.

Comment: I do not understand exactly why $1 <= K(x - a)$ implied that $x = a$

Comment: I guess the equality of $f(a) = 0$ could be derived by just plugging $x=a$ in the given inequality

Comment: $$  |f(x_\varepsilon)| \le K\int_{a}^{x_\varepsilon}|f(t)|dt \le K(x_\varepsilon-a)\varepsilon $$
How do you derive the left-hand-side inequality?!

Comment: I edited the post, refresh.

Comment: How do you know that the maximum of function $g$ will be epsilon?! Instead of epsilon, there should be the supremum of the function $g$ on that interval (i.e. absolute value of $f$)

Comment: This follows from the definition of $x_\varepsilon$.

Comment: Can you please exemplify more on the set of $x_{\epsilon}$?! I still can not figure out the meaning of this set. (pretty sure this comes from continuity of $f$, but I would be really appreciated if you could provide a little more details if possible)

Comment: By definition of $x_\varepsilon$, there holds that $|f(t)|\le\varepsilon$ for all $t\le x_\varepsilon$ (this has nothing to do with the continuity of $f$, it is by definition of the infimum).

Comment: So it means that $x_{\epsilon}$ is the smallest ("infimum") number for which $x_{\epsilon} > a$ and $|f(x_{\epsilon})| >= \epsilon$? Meaning that for all numbers $y$ less than $x_{\epsilon}$, we will know that $|f(y)|$ is less than $\epsilon$?

Comment: Oh, now I see the point. But now arises another question: how continuity of $f$ will guarantee that for any small values of $\epsilon$, you can find that the function values near the neighbourhood will be larger than $\epsilon$? I guess there should be another point $y_0$ if we are dealing with continuity

Comment: Moreover, you obtained that $x_{\epsilon}$ is larger than one quantity. How can you take the limits for each $\epsilon$ where you do not have control over the choices of $\epsilon$

Comment: I do not claim this. The assumption $f\neq 0$ implies that $x_\varepsilon$ is-well defined. Moreover, continuity of $f$ guarantees that $x_\varepsilon \to a$ as $\varepsilon\to 0$. On the other hand, the calculation shows, that for any $\varepsilon>0$ we have that $x_\varepsilon >\frac{1}{K}+a$ (note that this bound is independent of $\varepsilon$!), which is a contradiction to $x_\varepsilon\to a$. Hence, $f=0$.

Comment: I agree with the well-definition of $x_{\epsilon}$. But, how do you get that $x_{\epsilon}$ approaches to $a$ whenever $\epsilon$ approaches to zero?!

Comment: This is because $f(a)=0$ and $f$ is continuous.

Comment: Honestly, the last part really lacks the mathematical rigor: how $f(a) = 0$ and continuity of $f$ directly implies that limit of $x_{\epsilon}$ approaches to $a$ whenever $\epsilon$ approaches to zero: This really requires mathematical formalism, intuitively this seems okay though (however, I am still confused on how you choose these $\epsilon$ values, as this is not correct to assume that you have the control of the choices of these $\epsilon$ values.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/126304/discussion-between-snowflake-and-crankk).

Answer (score 1):

Here's a very similar approach, not sure how rigorous it is

1. Prove that $g(a) = 0$

$$g(a) \leq K \int_{a}^{a}g(x)dx = 0$$

2. Choose a very small distance $\epsilon$

$$g(a + \epsilon) \leq K \int_{a}^{a + \epsilon}g(x)dx
\approx \epsilon K \frac{g(a) + g(a + \epsilon)}{2} + O(\epsilon^2)$$

Rearranging and setting $g(a) = 0$ we get

$$O(\epsilon^2) \geq g(a + \epsilon)(2 - \epsilon K)$$

For sufficiently small $\epsilon$ this is only possible if $g(a + \epsilon) = 0$.

3. The same argument holds for all points $(a, a + \epsilon]$, so they are all zero.
4. Shift the start if the integral $a \rightarrow a + \epsilon$ and continue doing steps 2 and 3 iteratively until we prove that all of the interval is zero.

The only problem I see with this proof is that maybe there exist some very weird functions for which point 2. does not hold for very small but finite intervals. I'm thinking about something like the [Weierstrass function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_function), but that is far beyond my understanding